# Why do some capacitors not have vents?

Tags: capacitor, electrolytic-capacitor, failure

Some (electrolytic) capacitors I have in a kit have vents, some do not (not on the top, not on the bottom).

The vents are there to safely let the gas out instead of letting the capacitor shoot.

So why don't all the capacitors have these? If they would fail (you never know): aren't the vented capacitors safer to use?

Comment: Besides that maybe you just can't see the vent mechanism, or they don't have liquid electrolytes and thus don't need vents, it can just be that they are old ones where it wasn't invented, or cheap ones where somebody saved 0.00001¢ per manufactured cap.

Comment: If it blows up inside a sealed appliance, it probably won't have enough energy to hurt you.  Larger caps have more potential for disaster. High capacitance leads to thinner insulating layer that can more easily fail. High voltage leads to more current if the cap fails.

Comment: Good to know!
@OskarSkog I also thought that they will emit a spark/small flame when popping -- is that correct? (From what I saw in some videos), couldn't that be dangerous if the capacitor comes into contact with a flammable material (like clothes)?

Comment: @KevinVanRyckegem: Depends on many factors.  A spark may be likely at overvoltage conditions.  Fuel + oxygen + enough heat or a spark = flame, if it sparks and it has an organic electrolyte you may get a flame.

Comment: @OskarSkog That explains. So does that mean any capacitor could have a flame in that condition? Or does having a vent or a weakened metal part (T/X as in the answer below) avoid a spark/flame?

Comment: @KevinVanRyckegem:  The threat isn't big enough, I think. Electrolytics in consumer appliances seldom fail violently. Consumer appliances are seldom near clothes (except for washing machines etc).  Class II appliances are sealed so a small flame inside them will soon die.  And unless you have fluffy or gasoline soaked clothes, they won't be /that/ easy to ignite, especially for the small electrolytics.

Comment: I think the weakened metal and vents are only used for letting out gas that builds up relatively slowly.  If the cap remains intact after having let out the steam, it won't spark or burst into flames.

Comment: @Kevin  I too was curious about this at one time.  I've noticed that it's the smaller electrolytics that often haven't got vents.  It's possible that small ones don't develop as much energy ( E=PV ) when they fail, because the volume is small.

Comment: Maybe it doesn't need a weak point (vent), but you need to determine whether or not it does. Some small diameter electrolytics don't have vents (how big is yours?). Assuming that it's an ordinary electrolytic, I would cut the printed shrink wrap off and look at the bottom. If there's no vent where there should be one, then that begs the question "What other corners were cut when it was made?". That capacitor could be trouble down the road.

Comment: It's not that complicated to manufacture a housing that has predetermined weak points even if you can't see them in the form of these usual cuts.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do you mean the "T", "X" or "K" on top of most electrolytic capacitors ?

[image]

Actually these vents are not vents but a deliberately made weak-point in the housing of the capacitor.

The vents are only needed for Capacitors which contain some electrolytic fluid which could start to boil and create pressure.

Not all capacitors contain electrolytic fluid, for example "Solid electrolytic capacitors" or "[Polymer capacitors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymer_capacitor)" don't.

[image]

Comment: Hm, but there is no vent and no weak-point in the housing. The capacitor looks like this: https://goo.gl/PwA0N1 however, the top is entirely flat; there is no weak-point. I thought this is an electrolytic capacitor and it should have the weak-point; in order to avoid them building up too much pressure during a failure. -- I should state that I bought these from a Chinese website, so I'm not sure about the quality. But is it right to assume that it is less safe not to have that? It seems like an important safety feature for such a capacitor.

Comment: Unless there's a respectable brandname on the capacitor, I would not trust it. It would be OK for some hobby use under and experiments but not in a hot power supply.

Comment: So I wonder, do some brands also have the left capacitor you show without the weakened (T/X thing) housing? Or is that just because I have gotten bad capacitors?
Out of curiosity: what could be the worst case of such a capacitor failing?
Thanks for the info!

Comment: Worst case failing? Along the lines of https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0OIGz9gHCRI

Comment: *do some brands also have the left capacitor you show without the weakened (T/X thing) housing?* Yes, the smaller value capacitors, older types (when doing this was not so common), Axial shaped capacitors (wires coming out on opposite sites). I have plenty in my parts drawer which do not have the weakened top.

Answer (score 3):

Small electrolytic capacitors (diameter 5 and 6.3 mm) usually don't have vents because:

- It's hard to manufacture a reliable vent on such small surface
- They don't generate enough energy (pressure) to be dangerous
- The bottom sealing is weak enough to blow relatively early in case of failure

As said before many axials, old or cheap electrolytics don't have vents.

Big screw terminals electrolytics have vents, it is generally a small hole with a rubber plug, not a weak point engraved in the housing.

You should not underestimate the risk of a capacitor blowing.
I've seen medium sized ones (diam 16-18 mm) make a dent in a steel 2 mm chassis, the same dent you can make by hitting it very hard with a hammer.
Even if there is no fire or projection, the noise of a big capacitor blowing can damage your hearing if you are too close.